# Repeating 3 letters up to 6 times only

Tags: java

I've been trying to use nested for loops to repeat the word, "hedgehog" with three letters up to 6 times only, however, it keeps going until it fully spells hedgehog.

```
public static String print3LetterSubstrings(String word) {
     for (int len = 3; len <= word.length(); len++) {
        for (int i = 0; i+len <= word.length(); i++) {
            System.out.println(word.substring(i, i+len));
        }
    }
    return word;
    }
```

What I want is to have just 3 letters that just repeat 6 times.

hed
edg
dge
geh
eho
hog

Comment: three letters or three words?

Answer (score 2):

If you always want three character substring(s) then `len` shouldn't change. You want to loop printing the substring from `i` to `i + len`. Like,

```
public static String print3LetterSubstrings(String word) {
    int len = 3;
    for (int i = 0; i + len <= word.length(); i++) {
        System.out.println(word.substring(i, i + len));
    }
    return word;
}
```

Outputs when called as `print3LetterSubstrings("hedgehog");` (as requested)

```
hed
edg
dge
geh
eho
hog
```